# How I can know today's date is Sunday or not?

Tags: swift, date, foundation

Very simple question,
but how can I know whether some date is Sunday or not?

I wanna get `Bool` from this.
Are there some sources? Thanks!

Comment: Use [`Calendar`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar) methods, e.g., [`Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293299-component). See [`weekday`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponents/1410442-weekday).

Comment: Thank you very much Rob! I will try! I tested on Playground with Demo, and I think I can solve. Thanks for your one point lesson!